# YII DAO - Sending Multiple queries to database and retrieving results

Tags: php, yii

I have scenario where I have to send different queries  to the database to get the result and display it.

Using $mysqli->multi_query in PHP we can send all the queries together to the database and get the results in one shot  .Here is the link for it
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Can I do the same using Yii Command ..? I see QueryAll is returning only for the first query If I combine the queries together separated by ";"

Thanks for checking .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an extension for this.

https://github.com/javijuol/yii-CDbExtendedConnection

It's in a very early stage. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank You . I will test it today and let you know the status on it .